# solr response in xml format

Tags: java, solr

I am trying to query Solr using certain fields and I want the response in XML format. Somehow I am not able to get the response in XML format even though I have set the parser to `XMLResponseParser`. Please check the code and let me know what is wrong in here:

```java
HttpSolrServer  solr = new HttpSolrServer(urlString);

String queryString ="*:*"; 
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery(queryString); 
query.setQuery(queryString); 
query.setFields("type", "typestring");
query.addFilterQuery("id"); 
query.setStart(0); 
query.setRows(100); 

solr.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());

QueryResponse resp = solr.query(query);
SolrDocumentList results = resp.getResults();
for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
    // I need this results in xml format
    System.out.println(results.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is using `SolrJ` as a `Solr` client. It's precisely done to avoid dealing with XML responses, and it provides a clean way to get `Solr` results back in your code as objects.

If you want to get the raw xml response, just pick up any java HTTP Client, build the request and send it to `Solr`. You'll get a nice XML String...

NOTE : You can use [`ClientUtils.toQueryString(SolrParams params, boolean xml)`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.html#toQueryString%28org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams,%20boolean%29) to build the query part of your URL

Comment: can we convert the SolrDocumentList into xml format?

Answer (score -1):

As Grooveek already wrote, SolrJ is intended to take XML parsing away from you as a user of the library. If you want to see the XML, you need to fetch the response on your own.

```java
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("*:*");
// set indent == true, so that the xml output is formatted
query.set("indent", true);

// use org.apache.solr.client.solrj.util.ClientUtils 
// to make a URL compatible query string of your SolrQuery
String urlQueryString = ClientUtils.toQueryString(query, false);

String solrURL = "http://localhost:8080/solr/shard-1/select";
URL url = new URL(solrURL + urlQueryString);

// use org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils to do the http handling for you
String xmlResponse = IOUtils.toString(url);

// have a look
System.out.println(xmlResponse);
```